# Python Matplotlib Installation Issue on Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, pycharm

Hi all I'm new to Python and I'm trying to run the below code in PyCharm on a Windows 10. I have Python 3.8 installed.

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

x = [1,2,3]
y = [1,4,9]
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

The full error message I'm seeing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 3, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 32, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", line 31, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as contour
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.1\plugins\python-ce\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1059, in <module>
    class StandardPsFonts(Fonts):
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 1066, in StandardPsFonts
    basepath = str(cbook._get_data_path('fonts/afm'))
  File "C:\Users\tom_p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 461, in _get_data_path
    return Path(matplotlib.get_data_path(), *args)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib' has no attribute 'get_data_path'
```

I've searched the internet for solutions and so far I've tried the following:

- Uninstalling and re-installing matplotlib
- Installing matplotlib version 2.1.2
- Installing matplotlib through anaconda
- Installing matplotlib with the code `pip3 install matplotlib`
- Running the above code in VS code

I'm able to run the code in VS code but then I run into errors when I'm trying to import data and I'd rather just be able to run the code in Python than start learning how to use VS code as well as Python.

I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By default PyCharm tries to show matplotlib plot is the sidebar. And can't by some unknown reason. Please switch off "scientific mode" and repeat your attempt. Also try to run your code from the command line.

Comment: If you have `pip`, what do you get when you type `pip show matplotlib` in the terminal?

Comment: i'm guessing you're using either a conda or venv environment. Try recreating the environment

Comment: @snoopstick it gave the following:

`Name: matplotlib
Version: 3.2.1
Summary: Python plotting package
Home-page: https://matplotlib.org
Author: John D. Hunter, Michael Droettboom
Author-email: matplotlib-users@python.org
License: PSF
Location: c:\users\tom_p\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages
Requires: pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, numpy, python-dateutil
Required-by:`

Comment: You will need to install `pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, numpy, python-dateutil`. You can recheck in the part where this says `Requires: pyparsing, cycler, kiwisolver, numpy, python-dateutil`. Let me know if you still have some issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try in other IDLE. such as jupyter or google colab.

Comment: this should rather be a comment. Please do not post answers that do not answer OP's question.